# for which value of $a$ that$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u_{n}^{a}}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We are given an arbitrary real positive $u_0$. The sequence $\{u_n\}_{n\ge 0}$ is defined by $u_{n+1}=u_ne^{-u_n}$ for $n\ge 0$. Find the values of $a\in\mathbb{R}$ for which the sequence $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u_{n}^{a}}$ is convergent.

Thank you for your replies

Comment: Is there any reason to believe $a \gt 1$ is wrong, given that the tail of $\{u_n\}$ declines very slowly?

Comment: If $u_n<1$ then $u_{n+1}<1$, so $a>1$ can't be right for all $u_0$. Perhaps $a<-1$, but not $a>1$. @Henry

Comment: This recursion can be rewritten as $$u_{n+1}=u_0\exp\left(-\sum_{i=0}^n u_i\right)$$ Not sure if that helps.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I doubt $u_0$ matters very much as convergence is all in the tail. $0 \lt u_1 \lt 1$ and $u_{n+1} \lt u_{n}$ no matter where you start from

Comment: My point is,$u_n<1$ means that, if $a>0$ then $\frac{1}{u_n^a}>1$ so it is obviously not convergent when $a>1$. The problem is weirdly stated - you seem to be answering when $\sum u_n^a$ converges, then $a>1$ is a good guess. @Henry

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: OK so I seem to have had a brain freeze over signs. Perhaps I should have said $a \lt -1$?

Answer (score 4):

Hints :

1. First, using the fact that $xe^{-x}\le x$ and that the equation $x=xe^{-x}$ has only one solution (zero), show that $(u_n)$ converges to $0$.
2. Using the definition of $u_n$, show that $\frac{1}{u_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{u_n}\sim 1$.
3. By sum, conclude that $u_n\sim \frac{1}{n}$.