# Summability of iteratively defined series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of *nonnegative* real numbers such that
$$ x_{n+1} \leq e^{-x_n} x_n \qquad\mbox{for all } n\in\mathbb{N}.$$
Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ convergent?

Edit: Let us exclude the trivial case $x_n\equiv 0$. Take equality in the iterative definition, i.e., consider the sequence
$$ a_{n+1} = e^{-a_n} a_n \qquad\mbox{for all } n\in\mathbb{N},$$
subject to $a_1=1$. This puts $a_n$ into the form of the "iterative exponential" studied [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2964490/655547).. I thank [HallaSurvivor](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/655547/hallasurvivor) for providing this link. There it is shown that $a_n$ behaves like
$$\frac{1}{n+\frac12\log(n)+C+o(1)},$$
for some constant $C>0$, which clearly implies that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is divergent.

Consequently, no conclusion can be made about the convergence or divergence of $x_n$, unless more information is provided (again, excluding the trivial case $x_1=0$).

Thanks again to [HallaSurvivor](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/655547/hallasurvivor) for providing the relevant link.

Comment: It looks like homework you want us to do, what did you try ?

Comment: Let $x_1=1$ and use $=$ rather than $\le$.  See what you'll get.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! First, let me repeat advice from earlier in the comments: you should include some more details about what you've tried, where you found this problem, etc. Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Comment: Second, this is a fairly subtle problem, at least in the case this inequality is tight. As it stands, the answer is "it depends", since if we define $x_n = 0$ for all $n$, then the inequality is satisfied and the sum obviously converges. However, following Herb's advice, we can consider the case $x_0 = 1$ and $x_{n+1} = e^{-x_n} x_n$, which also obviously satisfies your inequality. In this case the analysis is much more subtle (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/868969/655547) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2964490/655547)) but one can show that the sum diverges.

Comment: Thank you HallaSurvivor for providing the links.. this essentially answers my question. My hope was that one could show convergence of the series a_n (defined above) at least for some a_1>0, which would imply convergence of the series x_n for the same x_1. But I believe that the series a_n actually diverges for any a_1>0, so it is of no use as a comparison criterion for x_n.